# Opportunity Owner change via Account Owner change nets odd result

Tags: apex, ownership

When I update an account owner, it updates any open opportunities if the original owner is identical to the original account owner.

Weird behavior: Opportunity.AfterUpdate trigger does not correctly identify the oldList.OwnerId as the original owner.  Both oldList and newList have the same owner (the new one).  Therefore, all my afterUpdate triggers that look for ownership changes are not working...

Anyone experience this?  Do I need to create my own Account.AfterUpdate trigger that updates all open opportunity owners to get around this??

Comment: I have run into this before (on contact owner changes via account owner changes) and I had to do just what you said.  Handle it from the Account trigger as for some reason the child triggers do not pick up on the change.

Comment: Ok, just did that, but problem is that it sneaks in prior to any account trigger, so I still cannot detect any changes to opportunity ownership... Is there a way to turn that off on the salesforce side now that I've built my own?